# How to specify a row background in table with iText5

Tags: itext

When creating a PDF table with iText5, it is possible to create a table background by implementing a `PdfPTableEvent` and a cell background by implementing a `PdfPCellEvent`.

But what about a row background? How can I create that?

The reason is because I want to create a calendar table like in the image below:

[image: calendar table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you have included the answer in your question: you have to use a table event. Take a look at the [RowBackground](http://developers.itextpdf.com/node/2509#2822-rowbackground.java) example. It contains a table event `RowBackgroundEvent` that allows you to create a table event to draw the background of a single row.

```
public class RowBackgroundEvent implements PdfPTableEvent {
    // the row number of the row that needs a background
    protected int row;

    // creates a background event for a specific row
    public RowBackgroundEvent(int row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    /**
     * Draws the background of a row.
     */
    @Override
    public void tableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] widths, float[] heights,
        int headerRows, int rowStart, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        float llx = widths[row][0];
        float lly = heights[row];
        float urx = widths[row][widths[row].length - 1];
        float ury = heights[row - 1];
        float h = ury - lly;
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.BASECANVAS];
        canvas.saveState();
        canvas.arc(llx - h / 2, lly, llx + h / 2, ury, 90, 180);
        canvas.lineTo(urx, lly);
        canvas.arc(urx - h / 2, lly, urx + h / 2, ury, 270, 180);
        canvas.lineTo(llx, ury);
        canvas.setColorFill(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        canvas.fill();
        canvas.restoreState();
    }
}
```

This is how this event is used:

```
public void createPdf(String filename) throws SQLException, DocumentException, IOException {
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    // step 2
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    PdfPTableEvent event = new RowBackgroundEvent(3);
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(7);
    table.setTableEvent(event);
    table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 8; j++) {
            table.addCell(String.valueOf(j));
        }
    }
    document.add(table);
    // step 5
    document.close();
}
```

As you can see, we want a background for the third row. The result looks like this:

[image]

You can tweak the `llx`, `lly`, `urx`, and `ury` value if you want to adapt the size of the background bar.

If you can draw the background of a single row, you can extend the code to draw the background of more than one row.

Comment: Thanks, Bruno. BTW excellent job on all those iText examples! I have learned a lot from them.

Comment: Thanks, such feedback is much appreciated.